# JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails, and my js code is not running. My program should output the result of checking a number for a palindrome on the same page, without switching to a new one, but when I press the output button, nothing happens. The js code is enabled in the browser, all the necessary libraries seem to have been downloaded (however, you can still write to me that you need to double-check). The browser also shows the 200 status for js requests. Why aren't they working?

Сode :

```
# app/controllers/palindrome_controller.rb
class PalindromeController < ApplicationController
  def index; end

  def show
    @number = params[:number]
    @error = validate_input(@number)
    calculate_palindrome unless @error

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
  end

  private

  def validate_input(number)
    return 'No number entered' if number =~ /\D/
    return 'The number is already a palindrome' if number == number.reverse

    nil
  end

  def calculate_palindrome
    @number = @number.to_i
    @results = []
    while @number.to_s != @number.to_s.reverse
      @results << @number
      @number += @number.to_s.reverse.to_i
    end
    @results << @number
  end
end
```

```
<!-- app/views/palindrome/index.html.erb -->
<h1>Testing the palindrome hypothesis</h1>
<%= form_with url: '/palindrome/show', method: 'get', remote: true do %>
  <%= label_tag :number, "Enter a number:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :number %>
  <%= submit_tag "Check" %>
<% end %>
<div id="results"></div>
```

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'palindrome#index'
  get 'palindrome/show', to: 'palindrome#show'
end
```

```
<!-- app/views/palindrome/show.js.erb -->
<% if @error %>
  $("#results").html("<p><%= @error %></p>");
<% else %>
  var table = "<table><tr><th>Step number</th><th>Current value</th></tr>";
  <% @results.each_with_index do |result, index| %>
    table += "<tr><td><%= index + 1 %></td><td><%= result %></td></tr>";
  <% end %>
  table += "</table>";
  if ("<%= @results.last.to_s %>" == "<%= @results.last.to_s.reverse %>") {
    table += "<p>The hypothesis is confirmed</p>";
  } else {
    table += "<p>The hypothesis has not been confirmed</p>";
  }
  $("#results").html(table);
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 7, I recommend switching to [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/introduction).
It is way better for running Javascript code in a Rails app. I use it in all of my Rails apps and it is installed on every Rails 7 app already.

I recommend the following tutorials:

- [The Odien Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/ruby-on-rails-stimulus)
- [Stimulus Rails 7 Tutorial - DEV](https://dev.to/bhumi/stimulus-rails-7-tutorial-5a6a)

Comment: thank you!!!!! stimulus solved my problem))

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting the form but not specifying the response format. It looks like respond_to is responding using the default response format (not JS) whereas you'll need to specify `palindrome/show.js` to alert the respond_to block that you're expecting JS.